# Wrapper Class in Apex

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

Can anyone please help me what wrong in the below code. I'm getting. `Illegal assignment from List to List` in `aWraper.items = spwrap;` this line.

```
 @AuraEnabled   (cacheable = true)
public static List<studentWrapper> getStudentsWrapperData (Id enrollmentName) {

    // return [select  Id, Name from Contact WHERE Enrollment_Name__c='a082w000000ZWB7AAO' and RecordTypeId ='0122w000000HM1kAAG'];
    List  <contact>  conlist =[select  Id, Name, Firstname, LastName, Gender__c, Birthdate, Grade__c,
                               (select  Id,  Program_Name__c, Program_Start_Date__c,  Program_End_Date__c, Program_Price__c
                                from Students_Programs__r) from Contact WHERE Enrollment_Name__c=:enrollmentName and RecordTypeId ='0122w000000HM1kAAG'];

    List<studentWrapper> conwrap = new List<studentWrapper>();

    for(contact con : conlist){
        studentWrapper aWraper = new studentWrapper() ; 
        aWraper.studentId = con.Id;
        aWraper.studentname = con.Name;
        aWraper.FirstName = con.Firstname;
        aWraper.LastName = con.LastName;
        aWraper.Gender = con.Gender__c;
        aWraper.Birthdate = con.Birthdate;
        aWraper.Grade = con.Grade__c;            
        aWraper.studentprogram = 'Program-'+con.Id;
        aWraper.studentOtherInfo = 'Other-'+con.Id;

        List<studentProgramWrapper> spwrap = new List<studentProgramWrapper>();
        for(Student_Program__c p : con.Students_Programs__r){
            studentProgramWrapper studentprgrawrapper =new studentProgramWrapper();
            studentprgrawrapper.programName =p.Program_Name__c;
            spwrap.add(studentprgrawrapper);
        } 
        aWraper.items = spwrap; 
        conwrap.add(aWraper);         
    }
    return conwrap;    
}

public Class studentWrapper{
    @AuraEnabled
    public Id studentId {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string studentname {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string Gender {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public date Birthdate {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string Grade {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string studentprogram {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string studentOtherInfo {get;set;}   
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<Items> items {get;set;}
}

public Class studentProgramWrapper{
    @AuraEnabled
    public string programName {get;set;} 
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<Items> items {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: `aWraper.items` is of type `List<Items>` , and you are assigning it a `List<studentProgramWrapper>` hence your error. What do you want to do?

Comment: Want to add array of object in `conwrap`

Comment: of which type? `studentProgramWrapper` ?

Comment: Yes `studentProgramWrapper `

Comment: public List<studentProgramWrapper> items {get;set;}

Comment: what is item here you have used in you code

Comment: You are assigning list< studentProgramWrapper> in list<items> that's the reason you are seeing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
public List<Items> items {get;set;}
```

With:

```
public List<studentProgramWrapper> items {get;set;}
```